# Template extensions during component extentions in Angular 5

Tags: html, angular, typescript, components, angular5

Anular 5: For clear structure of module i wanna make some AbstractParentComponent (that have reusable logic and template) and have possibility extend it:

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: ' //reusable header element with logic

              *here we should have ability to change part of tamplate*
               <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="customTemplate"> </ng-container>

       //reusable footer element with logic
'
})
export class ParentComponent{
//logic impl
```

And  i wanna ability create extended components that extend all parent logic but implement own part with custom template:

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: '
             //here i wanna extend parent template
             /*something like*/ <ng-template #customTemplate>
             //some template impl
</ng-template>'
})
export class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent{}
```

How it's possible to do ?

Comment: try to use   @ViewChild('changediv')
  changediv: TemplateRef<any>; but didn't get successes

Comment: have you solved?

Comment: unfortunately, no. i gone though other way without extention, but suppose that it's could be done with <ng-template #customTemplate> and @ViewChild

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-child',
  template: '<app-parent></app-parent>'
})
export class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent{}
```

Comment: how to inject our child template into part of parent template? your example just extend parent template.